# Select last records from table using group by

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I need to select last records from my table using group by UserID

[image]

I need to select StartDate,EndDate from last records grouping by userID

I am using code below

```
select StartDate,EndDate from  usersworktime   group by userid,StartDate,EndDate
```

The problem is that i am getting all rows instead only the last two of my table

Comment: What is the last record? Is the last StartDate or the last EndDate or the last ID?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Assuming* that the start and end dates will always be the highest values then you need to drop some of the columns from the `GROUP BY` (having all the columns in the `GROUP BY` is kinda like using `DISTINCT`) and use an aggregate function on the other column:

```
SELECT UserId,
       MAX(StartDate) AS StartDate,
       MAX(EndDate) AS EndDate
FROM usersworktime
GROUP BY UserId;
```

Otherwise, if that isn't the case, you can use a CTE and `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT UserID,
           StartDate,
           EndDate,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY UserID ORDER BY UsersWordTimeID DESC) AS RN
    FROM usersworktime)
SELECT UserID,
       StartDate,
       EndDate
FROM CTE
WHERE RN = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think i found a solution

```
SELECT usersworktimeid, userid,StartDate, EndDate
  FROM usersworktime
WHERE usersworktimeid IN (
SELECT MAX(usersworktimeid)
FROM usersworktime
GROUP BY UserID
);
```

Comment: That might work, but that's probably not the best solution here. It requires 2 scans of the table. You'll likely find better performance with a CTE or `GROUP BY` without a correlated sub-query.