# How to select data if same data from column will get data with condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want select data with condition

I have a table

```
Id|Name    |Age
1 |David   |1
2 |Aic     |2
3 |Owen    |2 
4 |Aic     |3
5 |Phuc    |3
6 |Aic     |4
7 |Ronaldo |4
8 |Ronaldo |5
9 |Ronaldo |6
```

How i can query if 2 record have same age like 2 it will select only record have name is "aic" else it get all if not same age will get all like that

```
Id|Name    |Age
1 |David   |1
2 |Aic     |2
4 |Aic     |3
6 |Aic     |4
8 |Ronaldo |5
9 |Ronaldo |6
```

Comment: What do you mean "same age"?

Comment: Do you want people with several rows/ages, or do you simply want Aic's rows?

Comment: Why not Owen? Age 2, same as one if Aic's ages. And what about Phuc? And why David?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54542685/select-last-records-from-table-using-group-by ?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson it mean if 2 record have same age like 2 it will select only record have name is "aic"

Comment: Do you want 'Aic' specifically or just because it comes first when sorted? I mean if you had someone with the name 'Aaaa', would you still want 'Aic' then or 'Aaaa'?

Answer (score 1):

You can try using `row_number()`

**[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=285e9df7de6474b2df23ef6f449edca1)**

```
select id,name,age from 
(
select id,name,age,row_number() over(partition by age order by name) as rn
from tablename
)A where rn=1
```

OUTPUT:

```
d   name    age
1   David   1
2   Aic     2
4   Aic     3
6   Aic     4
8   Ronaldo 5
9   Ronaldo 6
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can use this ** `row_number()` and `test1` is your Table name

```
select id,name,age from  ( select id,name,age,row_number() 
        over(partition by age order by name) as rownumber from test1 )A where rownumber=1
```

Answer (score 0):

One simple method is:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.name = 'Aic'
union all
select t.*
from t
where t.name <> 'Aic' and
      not exists (select 1 from t t2 where t2.age = t.age and t2.name = 'Aic');
```

This selects all "Aic"s and then all other ages with no Aic.  This can actually be combined into a single query:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.name = 'Aic' or
      (t.name <> 'Aic' and
       not exists (select 1 from t t2 where t2.age = t.age and t2.name = 'Aic')
      );
```

If you want to use window functions, I might suggest:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when name = 'Aic' then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by age) as num_aic
      from t
     ) t
where name = 'Aic' or num_aic = 0
```

Answer (score -1):

As you changed you question so use subquery

```
   select * from table where age in ( select age from table where name ='Aic')
```

As you again change your question so it would be

```
with cte as (
         select *,
    row_number() over(partition by age order by  name) as rn
     from table
        ) select * from cte where rn=1
```

Comment: i forgot if same age with get name "aic" and get all the rest

Comment: @ThienVu i think still your sample output is not correct check the eidited answer

Comment: @JoakimDanielson check the edit history of the question 1st then asking me something like that bro

Comment: @JoakimDanielson and for your kind information,in my opinion no point is cheap if you think like that way then please mention that ,hope you got my point

Comment: @JoakimDanielson use your reaction in some positive work that may help some others